# Alternative to Workspace API for LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, console, support, workspaceapi

According to [Lightning Experience Roadmap](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.lex_roadmap.htm&type=5) there is no hope for support Console Workspace API with Lightning Web Components in near future. When we create LWC application for Salesforce Console - one approach is to wrap lwc component in aura component. Is there any other possibilities to open console tabs and subtabs without using aura framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [LMS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel).

If you use Lighting Messaging Channel you can put your Aura component anywhere. I have custom page templates in my App and I put this component there (use it for Utility bar API), you can also put this component into Utility Bar.

I don't remember if Console Apps support it but you can create Hidden Utility Component and put in it your Aura logic, so it's present on the page but doesn't take space in the DOM, so you don't need additional styling to hide it.

Comment: how can be created Hidden Utility Component? Please can you share how it can be done?

Comment: I replied to you on another question)

Comment: you still cannot find how to do it?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:backgroundUtilityItem/documentation

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround although be cautious with it because it's not declared by SF and therefore not supported - you can directly dispatch "internalapievent" configured to a specific format:

```
new CustomEvent("internalapievent", {
   bubbles: true,
   composed: true,
   cancelable: false,
   detail: {
     category: "workspaceAPI",
     methodName: methodName,
     methodArgs: methodArgs,
     callback: (err, response) => {
       if (err) {
           return reject(err);
       } else {
           return resolve(response);
       }
     }
   }
 })
```

[Detailed guide here (Solution #2)](https://mtr-design.com/news/salesforce-mini-how-to-open-a-subtab-in-console-from-lightning-web-component)