# Lightning web component navigation

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningnavigation

I need to view record page in Console subtab when I click yhe link in lwc.

Comment: Check whether this resolves your issue. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280599/navigate-from-one-lightning-web-component-to-another-via-lightning-navigation

Answer (score 1):

Edit: possible duplicate, please see this QA - [Alternative to Workspace API for LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/336019/alternative-to-workspace-api-for-lwc?r=SearchResults)

Console subtab navigation is accessible via the workspace API:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_openSubtab.htm

This is not currently supported in LWC:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/get_started_supported_experiences

You would need to wrap your LWC in an Aura component, fire an event from the LWC, handle the event in Aura and perform the navigation.