# How to close LWC Quick Action without reloading the page?

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal, lightning-quickaction

The solution I found is to reload the page, both to cancel and to save.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="slds-float_right botoes">
                        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="Neutral" type="Cancel" name="Cancel"
                            label="Cancelar" onclick={closeAction}>
                        </lightning-button>

                        <lightning-button class="slds-p-horizontal_x-small slds-m-top_small" variant="brand"
                            type="submit" name="save" label="Salvar" onclick={handleSalvar}>
                        </lightning-button>
                    </div>
```

JS Code:

```
closeAction() {
        window.location.reload();
    }

handleSalvar(event) {
        event.target.disabled = true;
        createItem({
            OpptId: this.internalrecordId.Id,
            Categoria: this.categoriaselect,
            TipodeVenda: this.tiposelect,
            Fabricante: this.fabricanteselect,
            ValorVenda: this.valorvendaselect,
            Produto: this.produtoselect,
            ValorCompra: this.valorcompraselect,
            Bu: this.buselect,
            Margin: this.marginselect,
            Arquiteto: this.arquitetoselect,
            QuemPaga: this.quempagaselect,
            Fornecedor: this.fornecedorselect,
        }).then((data) => {
            window.console.log(data);
            if(data == 'success'){
                this.createToastEvent('Item adicionado com sucesso');
                this.closeAction();
                }
        }).catch((error) => {
            error && window.console.error(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error)));
        });
    }
```

I Try to use other solution, but not working...
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `CloseActionScreenEvent` to close the Quick Action.

```
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';



closeAction() {
   this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
}
```

**Example:**

sampleLWCQuickAction.js

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from "lightning/actions";

export default class SampleLWCQuickAction extends LightningElement {
  handleCase() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
  }
}
```

sampleLWCQuickAction.html

```
<template>
  <lightning-quick-action-panel header="My action">
    Here's some content for the modal body.
    <div slot="footer">
      <lightning-button
        variant="neutral"
        label="Cancel"
        onclick={handleCase}
      ></lightning-button>
    </div>
  </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</template>
```

sampleLWCQuickAction.js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    </targets>
     <targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
      <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
    </targetConfig>
  </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: It is working absolutely fine in my dev org. I have updated the answer with the example.

Comment: Thanks Friend! It's Working, the problem was in XML tag...
<actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>

Answer (score 5):

Per today's Summer 21 release webinar, you will need to do two things
Add a new import:

```
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
```

Then add a simple method to close it:

```
closeQuickAction() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    }
```

You can then call that and it will close the quick action. More details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/05/learn-moar-with-summer-21-lwc-quick-actions.html)

H/T to [Fabien Taillon](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/10350/fabien-taillon) for the heads up on this one

Comment: Not working because is a LWC, and not Aura Comp..

Comment: Definitely works for LWC, but you need to be using Summer 21 API version I think

Comment: Thanks Friend! It's Working, the problem was in XML tag... <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your LWC component into Aura, pass event to it when you want to close and it'll call `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();`

you can also use the same approach I described here - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/336026/16508.

TLDR; you can create Aura component which will use `QuickActionApi` and communicate with it via Messaging Channel.